# How to extract tiny broken screws

Tags: screws

I apparently have a very hard wooden door because I broke two tiny screws in a row trying to install a hook (Yes I made a pilot hole).

Any advice on how to get these out? The pliers I own won’t grip them, they only stick out by 1 or 2mm. I tried a screw extraction kit even the smallest bit was too big for these screws.

[image: image of the screws with fingers to scale]

Answer (score 3):

Cover them with a bigger hook?

Seriously, though, I’d use a punch to drive them below the surface, then patch and paint.

You could run a drill bit down beside them a few times and have a chance at extracting with vise grips, but you’d still have a big hole to patch and paint.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, driving them in deeper in the face of the door will be difficult at best. To do this, which is possible, the door needs to be solidly backed so it has no "give" when the screws are driven in. That said, if you are successful in doing so, the door material will still need to be carved out so the soft door surface that is swelled out around the broken screws can be cut back to solid material so it can be filed with a filler or putty of a sort.

My suggestion would be to use a Dremel tool with grinder, right angle grinder, or attachment for a drill to remove the metal that is above the  door's face. Doing this, you will also remove the soft material that is above the surface so it is ready to take the filler needed to restore the finish of the door.